# How does a rocket moves upwards to escape Earth's gravity?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, rocket-science

Is it true that when a rocket from earth is launched to the space the the rocket applies a force and the air gives an opposite reaction of force and so the rocket moves upwards?

Comment: Air? Do you mean the exhaust gas?

Comment: This article https://www.popsci.com/military-aviation-amp-space/article/2009-07/new-york-times-nasa-youre-right-rockets-do-work-space  seems relevant...

Comment: It means that the rocket moves upwards due to pressure from the nozzle which causes a reactant force on the rocket. Is it so .

Answer (score 2):

no, it is not. the presence of air has nothing to do with why the rocket can move. the rocket's engine generates thrust by throwing mass (extremely hot gas) out the nozzle at great speed. this creates a reaction force on the engine in the direction opposite to the exit direction of the hot gases and the rocket accellerates upwards. check wikipedia for more details and equations.

Comment: The force involved is not a reaction force in the usual sense of the word.  The force that propels the rocket is the force of the expanding gas on the nozzle.

Comment: @garyp, is this statement at the Wikipedia article [Rocket engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocket_engine#Nozzle) article wrong?  *"About half of the rocket engine's thrust comes from the unbalanced pressures inside the combustion chamber, and the rest comes from the pressures acting against the inside of the nozzle (see diagram)."*

Comment: @AlfredCentauri The text that you quote seems right.  Expanding gas applies pressure to the combustion chamber walls (one of which is open to the nozzle and not producing thrust there) and nozzle creating thrust.  The caption to the diagram cited, on the other hand, I don't understand. *From Newton's third law, equal and opposite pressures act on the exhaust, and this accelerates it to high speeds.*  If equal and opposite pressures act on the exhaust, it would not accelerate.  I don't understand what that caption is getting at.